# FakeObject for php-composer or RootPackageInterface

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, composer-php

I develop a php-composer plugin. And it use `RootPackageInterface` for getting some information like package name, version, and etc.
In Unit tests i want to mock `RootPackage` object. Did Somebody see [FakeObject](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/23/built-in-fake-objects.html) implementation for Composer or RootPackageInterface?

Yes, i know that i can mock this interface, but it is some verbosely.